# What is a chat invite?

Tags: support, chat, moderator-tools

On chat profiles, there's a metric in the user stats box that tells you how many invites you've sent:

[image: Chat stats]

There's no tooltip explaining how to send invites or how this number is calculated, the only thing I can gather is that this information is private (though I don't mind people knowing that I've sent at least 13).

I've invited many users to chat through comments and such, but I have no clue what this particular statistic is tied to. What counts as a chat invite?

Comment: "I don't mind people knowing that I've sent at least 13" - lol, actually only mods see these numbers :)

Comment: This is some moderator tool, [this is what we mortals see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/UiK8k.png).

Comment: @ShadowWizard is is the same for your own chat profile? Because I can only see the information for user who have Graphic Design set at their parent site

Comment: I don't see this in my own profile, and makes sense you can see only for those with Graphic Design as parent site, as you're moderator only there. If I have to take a guess, it's the amount of chat invitations the user sent, since it's causing the target user who was invited to get inbox item and is not limited afaik, it can lead to trolling - seeing number like 1000 there might help finding such a troll and stop him/her.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A chat invite is what happens when you 'invite' someone to a room they're not in right now. You do this from their profile:

[image]

I just tried using that button, and it incremented the counter in my profile.

Another case of inviting is when you create a room for yourself and someone else (using the next button to the one circled on the screenshot or [directly in some room by clicking someone's avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAXZA.png)), or click "move discussion to chat" on some question of yours.

Comment: I don't recall ever clicking that button let alone 13 times :S! Perhaps there is something else contributing?

Comment: @JohnB Superpings could count, not sure.

Comment: Maybe a super ping? Since it's also causing an inbox item with invitaton, it's very likely. /cc John

Comment: that sounds plausible, would you mind if I tested it on you @ShadowWizard?

Comment: @JohnB sure, go ahead! :)

Comment: Just tried it, looks like super pings don't count, at least in my (rather limited) test.

Comment: @Sha Creating a room for yourself and some user invites another user also.

Comment: Cool, @nicael, makes sense. :)

Comment: The room for another user and myself button incremented it straight away, that's a button I know I've clicked. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm guessing when you move 140 chat messages from one room to another, and that pings everyone involved with "[room-owner] has invited you to [new-room]. check your invites" - that it also increments that counter.